# How can I wrap sequential list items with same text values in a new element?

Tags: jquery, html, duplicates

I want to wrap elements to a new DIV if a child element of it has the same content of another child element. For example:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 3</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 4</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 5</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So if the content of the DIV with class ticketgroup of the `<li>` is the same I want this `<li>` items to `wrapAll()` to a DIV called `<new>`. It would output it like:

```html
<ul>
  <div class="new">
    <li class="product_item">
      <h2>Product 1</h2>
      <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
    </li>
    <li class="product_item">
      <h2>Product 4</h2>
      <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <li class="product_item">
      <h2>Product 2</h2>
      <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
    </li>
    <li class="product_item">
      <h2>Product 3</h2>
      <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
    </li>
    <li class="product_item">
      <h2>Product 5</h2>
      <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't possible in the manner you're attempting as the HTML output you're trying to create is not valid. The only child elements allowed in a `ul` are `li`. Also there is no `<new>` element in HTML, so that is also a problem.

Comment: You might explain what problem you're trying to solve instead of asking about one particular fix. Chances are it's been faced before and there's a more elegant solution to be had. I have a hunch just breaking up the list into several is a better approach.

Comment: WooCommerce creates this code in the product grid with `h2` and `div` in the `<li>`. sorry with `<new>` I meant `<div class="new">`

Comment: Like Rory said, you can't group list items like that. Break up the list or otherwise style the list items. Add more information to your post and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your essential question, you'd need to compare the `text()` values for each `$('.ticketgroup')` array element. It would get a bit twisty to group them because you'd need to keep track of adjacent values and store the subset.

Here's pseudocode for one approach:

```
let matches = {
    // key (list item string): value (array of matching list item indexes)
};

$('li.product_item').each(function() {
    let myString = $(this).find('.ticketgroup').text();

    // check whether myString exists as a key in matches
        // if so, add its index to an array on that key
        // if not, add it as a new key with an empty array as its value
});

// now examine all the arrays and look for sequential indexes
// use those to break up the list or add styling classes
```

As you can see, it's not an easy thing. If it's a matter of making the matching items visually similar, and you know what strings are typically expected, just do some styling:

```
$('.ticketgroup').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'Dayticket weekend') {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('dayticket-weekend');
    } 
});
```

Then you can style those list items differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to do it this way, not the nicest code but it works. Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkg6ap05/2/) or the code snipped below

```js
var searchedNode = "";
var index = 1;


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ticketgroup").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();


    if (searchedNode === $(this).text()) {
      return false;
    }

    var ticketGroup = $(".ticketgroup").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() === text;
    })


    if (ticketGroup.length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('.product_item').wrap("<div class='new'></div>")

      var group = $(".ticketgroup:contains(" + text + ")");

      for (var i = 1; i < ticketGroup.length; i++) {
        var productItem = $(ticketGroup[i]).closest('.product_item')
        productItem.appendTo($(".new:nth-of-type(" + index + ")"));
      }

      searchedNode = $(this).text();
      index++
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 3</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 4</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekend</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_item">
    <h2>Product 5</h2>
    <div class="ticketgroup">Dayticket weekdays</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```